# attempting to load redirect to a jsp using state.go in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I am attempting to redirect to another jsp using state.go in angular. The argument passed to the state.go loads a get url specified in spring controller The page specified never redirects when called. Here is a snippet

```
<script>
    var nr = angular.module('nr', []);
    nr.controller('nController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function ($scope, $http, $state) {

$scope.bookEdit = {
    bookEdit: function () {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/book/edit',
        data : $scope.nredit
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if (response.status == 204) {

        } else if (response.status == 200) {
            $scope.nredit = {

           };

           $state.go('/bookroom'); //a get method defined in spring controller

       }
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(response));
   });    
},
```

Please what could I be doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to utilize the state object so you have to reference the state, and not the url/path. So where you define the state - is what is referenced in the state.go method.

```
$state.go('bookroom')
```

Route definition

```
const bkRoom = {
    url: '/bookroom',
    views: {}
};

$stateProvider.state('bookroom', bkRoom);
```

Comment: You have to set up the state object and then assign the state as noted in the last line.  UI-router will grab the state (the constant bkRoom) and look at the views/url and redirect it accordingly